# How to have a sub-branch and keep it up to date with the parent branch?

Tags: git, github, gitlab, branch, git-branch

I want to have two branches: `main` and `sub`.

Let's say the folder structure of `main` branch is this:

```
.
├── folder_1/
│   ├── folder_1.1/
│   │   └── file.txt
│   └── folder_1.2/
│       ├── file.txt
│       └── another_file.txt
└── folder_2/
    ├── folder_2.1/
    │   └── file.txt
    └── index.txt
```

And then I want the `sub` branch to include only the contents of `folder_2` in `main` branch. So, `sub` branch structure should be like this:

```
.
├── folder_2.1/
│   └── file.txt
└── index.txt
```

And I want to always keep `sub` branch up to date with the `folder_2` of the `main` branch. Either automatically or manually **with git commands**.

And obviously, I want these two branches to be in the same repository.

Is there any way I can achieve this?

Comment: ahhh.... why? Is a _sparse checkout_ not good enough to achieve that?

Comment: *"folder structure of main branch is"* - you should realize that git branches are pointers to commits, they don't contain any files and don't have folder structure. And it seems to be that in this case you should create two separate repositories instead.

Comment: @user7860670 Yeah, seems like there's no other option unfortunately. Thanks! If you add this comment as an answer, I can mark is as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

One of the solutions is `git subtree split`. I don't know why `git subtree` seems deprecated and can't find its manual on https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git#_git_commands, although `git subtree --help` still works in the local.

Create `sub` from `main`.

```
git branch sub $(git subtree -P folder_2 split main)
```

The `git subtree` part creates a new history and returns its head. The new commits are created from those commits which are from `main` and touch the directory `folder_2`.

Update `sub` when necessary.

```
git checkout sub
newhead=$(git subtree -P folder_2 split main)
git merge $newhead
# Here we cannot use "git merge $(git subtree -P folder_2 split main)" for short,
# as it would raise an error complaining that "folder_2" does not exist
```

You can commit other changes on `sub`, although it might cause conflicts during the next merge. If any conflicts, just resolve them as usual.